# Order of operations between $\pm$ and derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If you have a function: $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$

And you want to find the derivative $f'(x) = (g(x) + h(x))' = g'(x) +h'(x)$

Does that mean the order of operations do not matter between $\pm$ and derivatives?

Comment: Yes it's true, try proving it using the definition $f'(x) = \lim_{x'\to x} \frac{f(x')-f(x)}{x'-x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) = g'(x) + h'(x)$ the differentiation is said additive (a property of linearity). Yes, the differentiation can be "swapped" with addition or subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct: $$f'(x)=(g(x)+h(x))'=g'(x)+h'(x)$$ and the same holds for $-$ (just consider the function $-h(x)$; this holds if both $g$ and $h$ are differentible at point $x$.
Indeed
$$f'(x)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+t)+f(x)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+t)+h(x+t)-g(x)-h(x)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+t)-g(x)+h(x+t)-h(x)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+t)-g(x)}{t} +\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{h(x+t)-h(x)}{t}$$
$$=g'(x)+h'(x)$$